# npm packager installation errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I ran the command  -

sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

But I am getting this Error. Can anyone help?

```
Password:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
101  7881  101  7881    0     0   5165      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  7696
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.6.2 - libarchive 2.6.2
install npm@1.0
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.106.tgz
0.5.11-pre
1.0.106
cleanup prefix=/usr/local
All clean!
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___npm.npm
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.0.106 Error: EACCESS, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Error: EACCESS, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/a4/a4oBVIXZEDS3kWEMo4Gh8U+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.4405/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/a4/a4oBVIXZEDS3kWEMo4Gh8U+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.4405/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCESS
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/a4/a4oBVIXZEDS3kWEMo4Gh8U+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.4405/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
It failed
```

Comment: `chmod` the directory that you want to install into at least temporarily...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the command using `sudo`:

```
sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Comment: yep .. figured out , my bad .. to spam

Comment: It's not spam if you re-format your question, so that if in future someone else faces the same problem, he/she can understand your question easily. You can also accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: shouldn't need to sudo, you should be owning your `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Answer (score 10):

They recommend to not use Sudo on this site: http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm,  and to instead use:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Followed by:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: Let me ammend this: NEVER DO THIS. It's an http link and you're executing a remote script :-).

Comment: You DON'T want to change permissions on /usr/local except if you really really know what you're doing.

Comment: @elementz How about just changing the owner of /usr/local/lib/node_modules ?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to install a given release from source
NOTE - this installs nodejs which gives you both node as well as npm, 
       they come together per release.

to start fresh remove prior node.js and npm installs as well as these :

```
sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore
```

to install nodejs and npm as yourself NOT root do these commands (OSX/linux) :

```
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/bin_0_10_32

mkdir ${NODE_PARENT}
```

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

```
cd node-v0.xxxx

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs

make -j8
make install   #  IMPORTANT this is NOT using sudo
               # not wanted since installing into $USER owned $NODE_PARENT
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

```
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

define environment variable NODE_PATH so node can find dir for modules otherwise
npm install xxx will put newly installed module into current dir :

```
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/lib/node_modules
```

when you use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

nodejs install gives you npm as well :

```
ls -la ${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/bin
```

Subsequent modules you install using global flag -g will automagically put
their ~binaries~ into above bin dir ... like browserify

Now put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such so your environment is setup